# Sanitize.css overwriting material ui css

Tags: reactjs, material-design, material-ui, next.js, sanitize

I am using *Next JS* (v9.2) and *Material-UI* (4.9.0).

I imported *sanitize.css* (v11.0.0) in *_app.js*.

When I am using material-UI outlined text-field, the outline is not displayed.

On removing *sanitize.css* from *_app.js*, the outline is displayed.

Is there any way to make material-UI overwrite other CSS?

Comment: just a suggestion, override the outline after loading sanitize.css on your text field using **!important** keywork. it is happening because sanitize may overriding outline property of text-field.

Comment: Are you referring to if they have competing styles?

Comment: You don't need to use `sanitize.css` with `Material UI`. It already should have what it needs to provide a consistent look across multiple browsers - https://material-ui.com/components/css-baseline/. `sanitize.css` and `Material UI` styles will override and there's no easy way to make them work together nicely.

Answer (score 0):

We don't need to use sanitize.css with Material UI. It already should have what it needs to provide a consistent look across multiple browsers - material-ui.com/components/css-baseline.

So I replaced sanitize.css and used . It solved the problem.